Carbon dates difference between two dates but i want the result to be days, hours and minutes
$dateStart = Carbon::parse($dateStart);
$dateEnd = Carbon::parse($dateEnd);

if ($dateStart && $dateEnd) {
    // Calculate the difference in days
    $days = $dateStart->diffInDays($dateEnd);

    // Calculate remaining hours without counting full days
    $hours = $dateStart->diffInHours($dateEnd) % 24; // Get the remaining hours within the last day

    // dateStart = 2024-07-01 10:00:00
    // dateEnd = 2024-07-20 19:42:00 
    return [
        // "days" => (int) $days, 
        "days" => $days, // 19.404166666667
        "hours" => $hours, // 9
    ];
}

dateStart: '2024-07-01 10:00:00'
dateEnd: '2024-07-20 19:42:00'
result would be:
"days" => 19.404166666667,
"hours" => 9,
i want:
"days" => 19,
"hours" => 9,
if i cast the days to (int) it worked but i get a warning, DEPRECATED  Implicit conversion from float 465.7 to int loses precision
is there a carbon way to do this?, what i want is the datetime difference but in fractional result: Days, Hours, Minutes

Carbon Difference in Time between two Dates in hh:mm:ss format

Implementation: https://phpize.online/s/0i

Honestly though, using the Carbon library is overkill.  It is more direct to just use PHP's native DateTime class: https://phpize.online/s/Ki  Sometimes devs "fall too much in love" with frameworks and libraries and forget the power and utility of native functionality.  (p.s. when I tested on PHPize, the diffInDays() method didn't return a float value, it returned the int that you desired.)

Whoops, there is a difference between d and days in PHP's DateTime diff() object -- better use days instead of d. var_export(['days' => $diff->days, 'hours' => $diff->h, 'minutes' => $diff->i]);
